# Windows Azure Storage emulator error occured

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage

I was trying to install the Windows Azure SDK when this shows up:

```
 "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference is not set to an instance 
    of an object at MicrosoftHosting.DevelopmentStorage.Tools.DSInit.Controller.PerformActions() at
    Microsoft.ServiceHosting.DevelopmentStorage.Tools.DSInit.DSInitProgram.Run(string args here)
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DSinit.Program.Main(string args here)"
```

I downloaded the Windows Azure SDK for vs2013 through web platform and this error shows up. but then i downloaded the separate program again but then, same error shows up.can someone please help me identify the root cause of this? Thanks